# SQL - add new column based off of existing column value (1 row)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Data:

[image]

Final result I intend to obtain is i.e, a new column 'payOff' has to be added and set to 'Y' when ss_use_TYPE='delta'

[image]

Any suggestions please ?

Comment: If you're simply adding a new column to DATA, then why does the SUM column change from 100 to 250? You didn't explain that part. So how should DATA look after you add the payoff column? What happened to the ss_use_type column? And why did two rows shrink to one row?

Comment: sorry, should have named the first column of first table differently; its the sum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach uses aggregation:

```sql
SELECT SUM(Sum) AS Sum, ss_source, case_id,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN ss_use_type = 'delta' THEN 1 END) > 0
            THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS payoff
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ss_source, case_id;
```